# Upgrading an old Visual Studio project using Visual Studio Build Tools

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I need to compile a project that was created using Visual Studio 2010, but I don't have Visual Studio.

Therefore I downloaded the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and tried to build it, what fails because the project is in Visual Studio 2010 format.

The error message suggest to upgrade it to 2017 format, however as I only have the VS build tools, there is not GUI I could start to load and upgrade the project. Also `devenv.exe` is not included in the VS build tools.

How do I upgrade the project so that I can build it, using only the Visual Studio 2017 build tools?

Comment: That's an exclusive feature of Visual Studio, so you cannot get it this way.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I upgrade the project so that I can build it, using only the Visual Studio 2017 build tools?

Without any more detail error messages/screenshot, it will be very hard for any of us to give a accurate answer. The best way to upgrade the project to Visual Studio 2017 is open the project with Visual Studio 2017, then troubleshooting unsuccessful project upgrades.

There is a guide [How to: Upgrade Projects Created in Earlier Versions of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms185327(v=vs.100)) and [Troubleshooting Unsuccessful Project Upgrades](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd627573(v%3Dvs.100))

Besides, [Porting, Migrating, and Upgrading Visual Studio Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) pointed:

> The following list describes support in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 for projects that were created in Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2010 SP1. You can use this list to help determine whether you can open a project as-is in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, or Visual Studio 2010 SP1, or whether you have to modify it to ensure compatibility.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I wrote I can't open the project in Visual Studio because I don't have Visual Studio, just the build tools.

Comment: I have noticed that. So I said **The best way to upgrade the project** is open it with Visual Studio, you have to install the Visual Studio. Otherwise, you have to know all the upgrade rules, then manually upgrade it manually.